# Thumbnail only showing link on mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

When trying to add a thumbnail to my wiki page it only shows a link to the picture. I'm presuming it has something to do with a missing module. Does anyone know what module controls this or if it is something entirely different?

Comment: We'll need to see some code, or atleast the precise steps so we can try to reproduce the problem. Please add more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out to need a rewrite line in the index.php

I found it here

http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Thumbnails

for anyone else who needs help with this sort of problem.

EDIT

adding these lines to index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files/thumb/./../.+?([0-9]+)px-(.+)$
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)px-(.+)$ /wiki/thumb.php?w=$1&f=$2 [L]
```

you'll need to change the regex pattern depending on your path names and when uploading a thumbnail you will need to check the image pixel resolution and define that when creating your thumbanil

hope this helps :D

Comment: Can you also include exactly what the answer was, rather than linking to an external resource? Thanks. Links can break, etc. etc.